# codeigniter - insert data by id on click on button

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a list of menus and when i click on menu shows a view with her details.
that's the view(menus_detalhes_user):

```
<p class="text-muted"><?php echo $menus->nome?></p>
                    <p class="text-muted"><?php echo $menus->preco?>€</p>
                    <a href="carrinhof/<?php echo $menus->id_menu?>" class="btn btn-default btn-xl">Add</a>
```

Now i need to add this menu to show in another view. I have that href, that 
supposedly sends me to function "carrinhof" on controller, but it doesn't happen. That href sends me to another controller and another function. 
Send me to the function that makes the select of all menus.

Controller:

```
function carrinhof()
{ echo 'Hello World!'; echo die();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3,0);

    if($id == 0)
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        redirect('controller/fmostra_menus_user');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('carrinho_model');

        $data['carrinho'] = $this->carrinho_model->getAllDisplayable_carr($id);
                    $this->load->library('form_validation');


        $this->load->view('carrinho_view',$data);
    }
}
```

Model:

```
function getAllDisplayable_carr()
 {
    $data['id_carrinho'] = $this->input->post('id_nome');
    $data['id_menu'] = $this->input->post('id_menu');
    $data['id_login'] = $this->input->post('id_login');

    $this->db->insert('carrinho',$data);
 }
```

I just want insert that menu on a table to show in another view, like an order that user makes and saves that menu in another area.
Thank's

Comment: shouldn't that be 3 segment url? `controller/method/id`, just use the url helper

Comment: @Rodrigo Duterte i don't understand your explanation. It's the first time that i work with codeigniter.

Comment: @RodrigoDuterte i already understand. I made those changes. But it still doesn't work, the url doesn't send me to the function. I think it's because the id returns to the function where i made the select. I don't know.

Comment: whats the name of the controller? url should consist `<controller name>/<method name>`

Comment: The controller name is controller and the method is carrinhof . So i need to put: `<a href="controller/carrinhof/<?php echo $menus->id_menu?>" class="btn btn-default btn-xl">Add</a>` ?

Comment: I already put but it doesn't work. He sends me to the function:
`function fmostra_menus()
 {
  $this->load->model('menus_model');
  $data['list'] = $this->menus_model->getAllDisplayable();
  $this->load->view('mostra_menus',$data);
 }`
I used this function to show all menus on a list. Maybe he sends to her because i use their variables view like i represent in my question.

Comment: You need to do the tutorial first so you understand the basics. Like looking at the code in your model - that won't work at all. Do the basic tutorial then it won't be as frustrating trying to figure it all out: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You're using variable ($id) on $data['carrinho'] = $this->carrinho_model->getAllDisplayable_carr($id);

but you're writing the function without variable in model
function getAllDisplayable_carr()